# How to watch films/images without X?

Tags: linux, graphics

I'm wondering if there is a way to watch films or images without running X server. I'm not using login manager - I log in to tty and start X server manually.

Hypothetical situation: I log in, but decide to only watch film, or maybe view few photos. I don't want to run X server and all the GUI stuff just for this purpose.

How can I watch films/images without X?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/46871/how-can-i-play-videos-in-a-framebuffer

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### For Images:

You can watch images with [**`fbi`**](http://linux.bytesex.org/fbida/):

```
NAME
       fbi - linux framebuffer imageviewer

SYNOPSIS
       fbi [ options ] file ...

DESCRIPTION
       fbi  displays  the  specified  file(s) on the linux console using the framebuffer device.  PhotoCD, jpeg, ppm,
       gif, tiff, xwd, bmp and png are supported directly.  For other formats fbi tries to use ImageMagick's convert.
```

Example command:

```
$ fbi path/to/file.jpg
```

---

#### For videos:

- You can use **`vlc`** from tty/console:

  Example command:

  ```
  $ vlc /path/to/file.mp4
  ```
- You can also use **`mplayer`**:

  ```
  $ mplayer /path/to/file.mp4
  ```

  Note: Video output drivers can be set by **`-vo`** option e.g `caca`, [**`fbdev`**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_framebuffer).<sup>([This](http://www.techiestuffs.com/how-to-watch-videos-in-linux-console-with-the-help-of-mplayer/) external article may help)</sup>

Comment: @MatthewRock Have you tried `vlc` without X session?

Comment: Works without X. Nice!

Comment: You must have permission to write to `/dev/fb0`. So either `sudo`, or `sudo usermod -aG video $USER`. Or else `fbi` fails, and `vlc` renders ASCII art. Maybe `audio` group is also needed.

Answer (score 4):

It's availability depends on the kernel features, but by using the Linux framebuffer provided by the kernel (or Direct Framebuffer library, which allows hardware acceleration) it should be possible to play video on the console, too.

For example, using MPlayer: `mplayer -vo fbdev filename.avi` or `mplayer -vo directfb filename.avi` should do the trick if all the required pieces are in place. As pointed out in the other answer, `vlc` might be easier to get working and it also supports both the old FB and DirectFB.

[Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_framebuffer) says the following about the framebuffer:

> There are three applications of the Linux framebuffer.
>
> - An implementation of text Linux console that doesn't use hardware text mode (useful when that mode is unavailable, or to overcome its
>     restrictions on glyph size, number of code points etc.). One popular
>     aspect of this is the ability to have console show the Tux logo at
>     boot up.
> - A possible graphic output method for a display server, independent of video adapter hardware and its drivers.
> - Graphic programs avoiding the heavy overhead of the X Window System.
>
> The last item includes several Linux programs such as MPlayer, links2,
>   Netsurf, fbida and libraries such as GGI, SDL, GTK+ and Qt Extended
>   can use the framebuffer directly. This is particularly popular in
>   embedded systems.
>
> There is now a library DirectFB which provides a framework for
>   hardware acceleration of the Linux framebuffer.

There's also a [Q & A exactly on this topic on this very same forum](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/223389/44760), and of course the old [Framebuffer HOWTO](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Framebuffer-HOWTO/).

Most notably, you should have `/dev/fb0` character device available (or more than one if there are multiple framebuffer devices available). At the bare minimum, the output of `zcat /proc/config.gz  |grep FB` should contain `CONFIG_FB=y`, but I'm not quite sure if the modern GPUs with DRM also need a sort of a legacy driver to make FBDEV work (in my case, I seem to have `CONFIG_DRM_I915_FBDEV=y` for the Intel GPU).

Comment: FATAL: Could not initialize video filters (-vf) or video output (-vo).

Answer (score 0):

You could run a super-light window manager based on wayland. For example I would recommend `rootston` (from the `wlroots` project). For example `rootston -E vlc`, you will get nothing else than vlc.

`rootston` has no menu, tray, clock, desktop, etc. There is nothing at all. However it is more of a proof of concept, and regularly crashes. It should be OK for watching a movie, though.

`rootston` **is not based on X** so it answers your question.

However for running application which are not compatible with wayland, `Xwayland` will be launched as a layer of compatibility and may contain X code.

If it's only the "GUI stuff" which bothers you, you could look into Openbox.